# File opening issue in gfortran in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm trying to run my project file with input and out text files. After compiling, I get the error which says it couldn't open the input text file, but it's in the same folder/path as the compiled script is. By the way, It's working on windows 7 like a charm!

**How can I run a FORTRAN 90 to open text files as its input and output on Ubuntu 16.04 without any error?**

Here is my code

```
!Seyed Ahmad Abtahi
!1396/04/14

PROGRAM ROKNI_PERSIAN_GULF

REAL::BATH(60,104)

INTEGER::X,nobu,nobv,nobu_start,nobu_end,nobv_start,nobv_end

CHARACTER*60::FILE1,FILE2

CHARACTER(8)::STR

! Give the path to the input and output file names 

FILE1 = "BATH4.TXT"

FILE2 = "BATHYOUT.DAT"

! Number of Open Boundaries of Horizontal vector V

nobv_start = 24

nobv_end = 103

nobv = nobv_end - nobv_start + 1

! Number of Open Boundaries of Vertical vector U

nobu_start = 1

nobu_end = 5

nobu = nobu_end - nobu_start + 1

! Reading raw data from input file and change the simple bathymetry to scientific numebers

OPEN (1, FILE = FILE1, FORM = 'FORMATTED', STATUS = 'OLD')

DO I = 1 , 60

        READ(1,*)(BATH(I,J),J=1,103)

        WRITE(*,*)(BATH(I,J),J=1,103)

ENDDO

CLOSE (1)

! Writing the calculated bathymetry to the output file

OPEN ( 2 , FILE = FILE2 , FORM = 'FORMATTED', STATUS = 'REPLACE', ACTION = 'WRITE' , RECL = 12*60*103 )

WRITE ( 2 , '(104(1P,E15.7E2))')(( BATH(I,J) , J = 1 , 104 ) , I = 1 , 60 )                                

! Writing NOBU coordinations

WRITE ( 2 , '(A5,I3)')'nobu:',nobu

DO X = nobu_start , nobu_end

    WRITE ( STR , '(I4)') X

    WRITE ( 2,'(2(A4))') ' 103', STR

END DO

! Writing NOBV coordinations

WRITE ( 2 , '(A5,I3)')'nobv:',nobv

DO X = nobv_start , nobv_end

    WRITE ( STR , '(I4)') X

    WRITE ( 2,'(2(A4))') STR , '   1'

END DO         

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Check the presence of the file once again. Linix is **case sensitive** so check that the file names are **exact** even with the capital letters. I suggest you tobnot use unit numbers below 10, because they are often reserved for special purposes. Most often 0,5 and 6 are reserved, but 1 and 2 could be as well for some compiler.

Comment: And next time, please show us the *exact* error message. Do not say *"the error which says it couldn't open the input text file"*, but show the error!. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: note the default directory is not the directory where the executable is, it is the directory where you execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

Define fileplace as a variable such as:

```
CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: fileplace = "./"
```

or everywhere you want.

Also define your file name in the open statement exactly with you file name and pay attention to the syntax. Unix is case sensitive to small and capital characters.

Change your open statement as below:

```
OPEN (1, FILE=fileplace//"BATH4.txt", FORM = 'FORMATTED', STATUS = 'OLD')
```

and also

```
OPEN ( 2 , FILE=fileplace//"BATHYOUT.dat"
```

Comment: Welcome Sophia. Be sure to take the [tour]. We do not sign our posts here, you name is put under your post automatically just right of your icon. Please study the formatting here. Do not use **bold** for code, use `code`. Also try to enable a spellchecker in your web browser.